# Select block of text and merge into new document

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hi I've looked online and just can't find the right answer. I have files which have `<!--#start#-->` and `<!--#stop#-->` through out them.
I only want the contents between those two strings. The code I have still prints out all the data including the start/stop lines.

```
Dim Prefix As String
Dim newMasterFilePath As String
Dim masterFileName As String
Dim newMasterFileName As String
Dim startMark As String = "<!--#start#-->"
Dim stopMark As String = "<!--#stop#-->"
'values from GUI form
searchDir = txtDirectory.Text
Prefix = txtBxUnique.Text


For Each singleFile In allFiles
    If File.Exists(singleFile.FullName) Then
        Dim fileName = singleFile.FullName
        Debug.Print("file name : " & fileName)
        ' A backup first    
        Dim backup As String = fileName & ".bak"
        File.Copy(fileName, backup, True)

        ' Load lines from the source file in memory
        Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(backup)

        ' Now re-create the source file and start writing lines inside a block
        ' Evaluate all the lines in the file.
        ' Set insideBlock to false
        Dim insideBlock As Boolean = False
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(backup)
            For Each line As String In lines
                If line = startMark Then
                    ' start writing at the line below
                    insideBlock = True
                    ' Evaluate if the next line is <!Stop>
                ElseIf line = stopMark Then
                    ' Stop writing
                    insideBlock = False
                ElseIf insideBlock = True Then
                    ' Write the current line in the block
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End If
Next
```

Here in another part of my code I'm grabbing the entity name from the main document and replacing it with the text between start and stop

```
Dim strMasterDoc = File.ReadAllText(existingMasterFilePath)
Dim newMasterFileBuilder As New StringBuilder(strMasterDoc)

'Create a regex with a named capture group.
Dim rx = New Regex("&" & Prefix & "_Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(?:-\d+)*)[;]")
Dim reg1 As String
reg1 = rx.ToString
Debug.Write("Chapter Entity: " & reg1)
Dim rxMatches = rx.Matches(strMasterDoc)

For Each match As Match In rxMatches
    Dim entity = match.ToString
    'Build the file name using the captured digits from the entity in the master file
    Dim entityFileName = Prefix & $"_Ch{match.Groups("EntityNumber")}.sgm"
    Dim entityFilePath = Path.Combine(searchDir, entityFileName)
    'Check if the entity file exists and use its contents
    'to replace the entity in the copy of the master file
    'contained in the StringBuilder
    If File.Exists(entityFilePath) Then
        Dim entityFileContents As String =   File.ReadAllText(entityFilePath)
        newMasterFileBuilder.Replace(entity, entityFileContents)
    End If
Next

'write the processed contents of the master file to a different file
File.WriteAllText(newMasterFilePath, newMasterFileBuilder.ToString)
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but i think the problem might be that the lines in `lines()` include  the carriage return and line feed characters. have you tried to use `line.Contains(startMark) instead of testing for equality?

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in my comment i think the problem might be that the lines in lines() include the carriage return and line feed characters. have you tried to use `line.Contains(startMark)` instead of testing for equality?

Also; is there a specific reason that you are reading all the lines and storing them first, before looping over them to check them? I think it would be more efficient to read, check and write in one go:

```
Using SR As New StreamReader(YourFilePath)
   Using sw As New StreamWriter(OtherFilePath)
       Do Until SR.EndOfStream
            line = SR.ReadLine()
            If line.contains(startMark) Then
                  ' start writing at the line below
                  insideBlock = True

                  ' Evaluate if the next line is <!Stop>
            ElseIf line.Contains(stopMark) Then
                  ' Stop writing
                  insideBlock = False

            ElseIf insideBlock = True Then
                  ' Write the current line in the block
                  sw.WriteLine(line)
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I gave it more thought on how the code should happen and this is what I came up with. I have a master document which contains &entity; elements. I need to capture the entity name, open that document and extract the contents between <!--# start/stop. Then close that document and return to the master document and replace the entity with the contents extracted from the other file. Then loop and do the same thing until there are no entities left in the master document