# Select text between key words

Tags: vb.net, text-extraction

This is a follow on question to [Select block of text and merge into new document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530575/select-block-of-text-and-merge-into-new-document)

I have a SGM document with comments added  and  comments in my sgm file. I need to extract the strings in between the start/stop comments so I can put them in a temporary file for modification. Right now it's selecting everything including the start/stop comments and data outside of the start/stop comments.

```vb
Dim DirFolder As String = txtDirectory.Text
Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(DirFolder)
Dim allFiles As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.sgm")
Dim singleFile As IO.FileInfo
Dim Prefix As String
Dim newMasterFilePath As String
Dim masterFileName As String
Dim newMasterFileName As String
Dim startMark As String = "<!--#start#-->"
Dim stopMark As String = "<!--#stop#-->"
searchDir = txtDirectory.Text
Prefix = txtBxUnique.Text

For Each singleFile In allFiles
    If File.Exists(singleFile.FullName) Then
        Dim fileName = singleFile.FullName
        Debug.Print("file name : " & fileName)
        ' A backup first    
        Dim backup As String = fileName & ".bak"
        File.Copy(fileName, backup, True)

        ' Load lines from the source file in memory
        Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(backup)

        ' Now re-create the source file and start writing lines inside a block
        ' Evaluate all the lines in the file.
        ' Set insideBlock to false
        Dim insideBlock As Boolean = False
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(backup)
            For Each line As String In lines
                If line = startMark Then
                    ' start writing at the line below
                    insideBlock = True
                    ' Evaluate if the next line is <!Stop>
                ElseIf line = stopMark Then
                    ' Stop writing
                    insideBlock = False
                ElseIf insideBlock = True Then
                    ' Write the current line in the block
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End If

Next
```

This is the example text to test on.

```
<chapter id="Chapter_Overview"> <?Pub Lcl _divid="500" _parentid="0"> 
<title>Learning how to gather data</title>
<!--#start#-->
<section>
<title>ALTERNATE MISSION EQUIPMENT</title>
<para0 verdate="18 Jan 2019" verstatus="ver">
<title>
<applicabil applicref="xxx">
</applicabil>Three-Button Trackball Mouse</title>
<para>This is the example to grab all text between start and stop comments. 
</para></para0>
</section>
<!--#stop#-->
```

Things to note: the start and stop comments ALWAYS fall on a new line, a document can have multiple start/stop sections

I thought maybe using a regex on this

```regex
(<section>[\w+\w]+.*?<\/section>)\R(<\?Pub _gtinsert.*>\R<pgbrk pgnum.*?>\R<\?Pub /_gtinsert>)*
```

Or maybe use IndexOf and LastIndexOf, but I couldn't get that working.

Comment: If it's selecting everything it could be that your test line = startMark is never matched.  Have you compared 'line' closely to see if it contains any non printing characters?  Or maybe try line.StartsWith(startMark)?

Comment: it's the only text on that line. Actually <elements> fall on their own line. If I could get the position of the end of <start> to beginning of <stop>  that's exaclty what I need

Comment: If this is a **SGML** document (as it looks like one), you could use an existing parser for SGML/XML/HTML like [SgmlReader](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader) or [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), both available as NuGet Packages. The former is available as NuGet Package in version 1.8.11, while the GitHub repo has v.1.8.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the entire file and split it into an array using the string array of `{"<!--#start#-->", "<!--#stop#-->"}` to split, into this

- Element 0: Text before `"<!--#start#-->"`
- Element 1: Text between `"<!--#start#-->"` and `"<!--#stop#-->"`
- Element 2: Text after `"<!--#stop#-->"`

and take element 1. Then write it to your backup.

```
Dim text = File.ReadAllText(backup).Split({startMark, stopMark}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(backup)
    sw.Write(text)
End Using
```

**Edit to address comment**

I did make the original code a little compact. It can be expanded out into the following, which allows you to add some validation

```
Dim text = File.ReadAllText(backup)
Dim split = text.Split({startMark, stopMark}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
If split.Count() <> 3 Then Throw New Exception("File didn't contain one or more delimiters.")
text = split(1)
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(backup)
    sw.Write(text)
End Using
```

Comment: I recieved System.IndexOutOfRangeException 'index was outside of the array' I replaced the code Dim insdieBlock As Boolean to end using and pasted your code there. Also what code do I use to extract the element and write it to my backup

Comment: Index out of bounds when indexing with 1 means that neither delimiter string was found, because only one element was returned (index 0 at most can be used in that case, right?). You can check for the existence of the delimiter strings before parsing it.

Comment: @MaxineHammett please see my edit. Test with the expanded code. If it throws that exception, break on `Throw New Exception ... ` and inspect `text` for inclusion of both delimiters.